# Magento 2 Payment and Review page

Tags: magento2

I want to display the error messages in payment and review page. Anyone has idea how to do it?

Comment: Write more detail

Comment: @SohelRana I want to display payment page error messages in payment page.

Comment: I am using below code to redirect and error message $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Your purchase process has been cancelled.'));
                return $this->_redirect('checkout', ['_fragment' => 'payment']); redirecting is working fine but error is not displaying in payment page